# Manually parse urls in ASP.NET-MVC-3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, url

I have a Controller with syntax like this:

`public class CrudController<TEntity> : Controller`

Now if I need a `CrudController` for Entity `User`, I just need to extend the `CrudController` like this

`UserCrudController : CrudController<User>`

Its working just fine. But, the thing is, the `UserCrudController` is simply empty. Also, there are some other `CrudControllers` which are empty too.

Now, I am looking for a way to avoid writing the empty crud controllers. I simply want to create Instances of `CrudController` with appropriate generic argument. Perhaps by a strict naming convention as described bellow.

- The URL will be like: `@Html.ActionLink("Create", "UserCrud")`
- When the URL will be received, it will try to locate the controller named `UserCrud` (The default thing)
- If it fails to locate `UserCrud`, `Crud<User>` will be created.

Now, I can do the things I want to do. But exactly where do I do these? Where is the url parsed in mvc?

Comment: You don't need to parse the URL. You just need to write a ControllerFactory.

Comment: Ok, let me learn about ControllerFactory. I'll be back soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With help of Craig Stuntz's comment on the question and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/568137/adding-a-controller-factory-to-asp-mvc) question and its accepted answer, I have solved my problem.

I have implemented a custom `CotrollerFactory`

```
public class CrudControllerFactory : DefaultControllerFactory {
    protected override Type GetControllerType(System.Web.Routing.RequestContext requestContext, string controllerName) {
        Type controllerType = base.GetControllerType(requestContext, controllerName);

        if(controllerType == null) {
            int indexOfEntityEnd = controllerName.LastIndexOf("Crud");
            if(indexOfEntityEnd >= 0) {
                string entityName = controllerName.Substring(0, controllerName.Length - indexOfEntityEnd - 1);
                // Get type of the CrudController and set to controller tye
            }
        }

        return controllerType;
    }
}
```

And then in `Application_Start()`, I added this line:

`ControllerBuilder.Current.SetControllerFactory(typeof(CrudControllerFactory));`