# Make inner class in controller callable from HTTP

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0

i have question about C# Controller. How to call inner class in C# Controller? For example, i wish to call **AdminController.Inner.Call()** from **JavaScript**.

```
    public class AdminController {

        public class Inner {

            public JsonResult Call() { }

        }

    }
```

Thanks for answers!

Everything what i read i know. This is just example, i need this for large project, about 3000 lines. If i have 5 functions for one page, i want to join it to one class, separately from others. And so others functions make same way.

Comment: Why do you need to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Haven't used controllers before personally, but after a quick read it looks like a pretty restrictive type. If the whole issue is calling an inner class method, why not just write a method on the top level class that calls the inner class's method and returns it's return?

ex.

```
 public class AdminController {

    public class Inner {

        public JsonResult Call() { }

    }

    public JsonResult InnerClassMethod { return this.Inner.Call(); }


}
```

Duct tape isn't pretty, but it works.

Comment: This doesn't work, AdminController doesn't have a `this.Inner` and apart from that it's the same as my answer.

Comment: Yes, I mistakenly treated it as an instance. Your code is more accurate.

Answer (score 0):

Either [write a custom ControllerFactory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/568137/adding-a-controller-factory-to-asp-mvc) or call it using an ActionMethod from your AdminController:

```
public class AdminController 
{
    public JsonResult CallInner()
    {
        var inner = new Inner();
        return inner.Call();
    }        
}
```

It does seem like you're actually trying to do something else though, can you explain what?

Comment: I have large project and i need more classes under master class Admin. I reorganize code for better practice. Therefore i can join more function about one tema to one class, and so other.