# return view() for all actions in controller .net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have one controller `HomeController.cs`.

In this controller I have some actions like about,contact etc.

If I want that will work I have to defined function to each view:

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult About()
    {
        return View();
    }
```

I want that for all the requests to the controller it will be return the `View()`, so I will not have to defined a function to each view.

***Update**
I want to know if there is some handler that will work something like this:

```
protected override void OnActionCall()
    {
        return View();
    }
```

Comment: What's the point here? This goes against the MVC structure principles.

Comment: Why? I have the same functionality in some actions. What's wrong?

Comment: So you're not being very clear on what you're trying to achieve. Please elaborate.

Comment: I don't understand what's not clear. I don't want to take care of each View that I add to the controller because in all the cases I just want to present the View but not change anything in the controller.

Comment: What you're doing is exactly that. Responding to an `action` by presenting a `view`, via the `controller`. What's to change here?

Comment: I don't understand anything on what OP is looking for.

Comment: I want to avoid having to set each action in controller

Comment: How can you expect to have an _orphan_ `action` with nothing on the `controller` to respond to?

Comment: You mean to say, if you're not doing anything in your action method except that single return statement, then you don't want to have that action method in your controller, is it?

Comment: I think you'll need a custom `controller` factory: [Adding a controller factory to ASP MVC](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/568137/adding-a-controller-factory-to-asp-mvc)

Comment: @MokshShah exactly! I was updated my question.

Comment: Have a look at @jumpingcode answer, it answers your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**WARNING: I would strongly advise against this as it pretty much defeats the purpose of using MVC but...**

You could create a general action that will find the view for you:

```
public ViewResult Page(string urlSlug)
{
    if (!this.ViewExists(urlSlug))
    {
        throw new HttpException(404, "Page not found");
    }

    return this.View(urlSlug);
}

private bool ViewExists(string name)
{
    ViewEngineResult result = ViewEngines.Engines.FindView(ControllerContext, name, null);
    return (result.View != null);
}
```

You will need to edit your `RouteConfig` though:

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Home_Page",
            url: "{urlSlug}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Page" },
            constraints: new { urlSlug = @"[A-Za-z0-9-]{1,50}" }
        );
```

Now if you look for `/about` it will look for that view. You will run into problems when you want to use `Model` data though. I think the time spent asking this question and implementing this solution would take a lot longer than simply having `return View()`

Comment: while this surely works, this is the kind of thing that goes against MVC conventions, and will be very hard to troubleshoot and maintain.

Comment: @Claies I wholeheartedly agree - I will put a warning at the top of my answer.

Comment: Honestly, I do not like that people use this argument. This is true, but sometimes this kind of solutions actually prevent problems. I think that the idea of the code is to find common ground, and this solution really find common ground. I would prefer to have a built-in .NET solution of course.

Comment: @mosh If you want a bunch of static pages...why not use static pages?

Comment: @jumpingcode I want to use other aspects of MVC like templates routs and other staff.